# Enviar una plantilla de whatsapp con archivos en twilio?

Tags: whatsapp, twilio

actualmente me encuentro trabajando con una integración con la API de whatsapp mediante twilio. Mi problema es que quiero enviar tickets de forma automática, sin embargo, la API marca que si el usuario no a iniciado un chat en las ultimas 24 horas debo enviar una plantilla predefinida en el mensaje de la petición, no tengo ningún problema enviando plantillas de whatsapp, pero cuando adjunto el archivo este no envía el cuerpo del mensaje y como no hay mensaje del usuario ni plantilla en el cuerpo, bloquea la salida del mensaje. Este es un problema que se pueda solucionar dentro de twilio o es un asunto que debo ver otro proveedor?. Si posteo acá es por que busco alguien que haya pasado algo similar, ya que el soporte de twilio y la documentación no han logrado ayudarme.

Gracias.